# HandleChallengeAsync is called in my AuthenticationHandler even when specifying a different scheme in a Challenge

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-web

I am registering my auth scheme at startup

```
var authBuilder = 
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddScheme<MyCustomHandlerOptions, MyCustomHandler>("MyCustomScheme", null)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

My custom auth handler doesn't do much yet

```
protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    Context.Response.Redirect("/MyLoginPage");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
}
```

Everything works when use an Authorize attribute with a scheme specified. I only want my Auth handler to be used when the scheme is specified like this.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyCustomScheme")]
```

I have created a Controller Action to force an Oidc Challenge.

```
[HttpGet()]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult SignInOidc([FromQuery] string redirectUri)
{
   string redirect;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri) && Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUri))
   {
      redirect = redirectUri;
   }
   else
   {
      redirect = Url.Content("~/")!;
   }

   return Challenge(
       new AuthenticationProperties 
       { 
           RedirectUri = redirect 
       },
       OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

The problem is, when I navigate to `Account/SignInOidc`, `HandleAuthenticateAsync()` is called in my custom AuthenticationHandler. Even though I am returning `AuthenticateResult.NoResult()`, the `HandleChallengeAsync()` method is still invoked.

This results in my page redirecting to my custom login page, instead of redirecting to the Oidc provider.

Is there a way to tell my Handler not to do the redirect when a challenge has been invoked for a different scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that my SigninOidc method was not supplying a redirect url. My app redirected to my oauth provider, and then transferred back immediately because I was already logged in.

This caused my app to do back to my default path (/), which kicked the whole auth process off again.

I am using a browser that doesn't have an address bar, so I didn't noticed the redirect.